# fancybox loading mystery object content in woocommerce - "requested content cannot be loaded"

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, fancybox

Up to date wordpress, woocommerce and fancybox

When scrolling through product images using easy fancybox from the product details page, fancybox is apparently attempting to load extra content from somewhere.

What I mean is, if I have a product with a total of two images, fancybox displays those images just fine, but then tries to load a third image or some kind of link or content and returns "the requested content cannot be loaded, please try again later". I can continue scrolling through this, but obviously, it is annoying.

Printful (a t-shirt dropshipper) is integrated with my woocommerce install. They recently rolled out a new tool that imports a product from the printful website into woocommerce. The import includes product info, description and an image, which I delete and replace with my own images. I believe the issue has something to do with this import tool. I have contacted printful but they are scratching their heads, so I am trying here.

I have tried deleting caches and playing with all the fancybox settings, different browsers.. I have spent an hour digging through forums. I am stumped.

I will post a link if requested, but i've had links to this particular website removed from stackoverflow by moderators (or someone).

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

RESOLVED (not at all)

I deactivated the printful integration plug in and the ghost images have disappeared. This solves the immediate problem, but creates another one in its place.